# Derivative involving summation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $f(\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i ^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i$.

Find $f'(\mathbf{x}).$ Then find the directional derivative in the direction $u=(1,0,0,0, ... , 0)$ at the point $(0,0, ..., 1)$

I have said that $f'(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \sum_{i=1}^n a_i=1+ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i .$ (at the point (0,0,....,1))

I don't know if this is correct so far or where to go next though.

Comment: $f'(\bf x)$ should be a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\nabla f=\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{a}
$$
so the directional derivative in the direction $(1,0,0,0,\dots,0)$ is
$$
\nabla f\cdot(1,0,0,0,\dots,0)=x_1+a_1
$$
at the point $(0,0,\dots,1)$, this is
$$
\nabla f(0,0,\dots,1)\cdot(1,0,0,0,\dots,0)=a_1
$$